# scipy lecture notes, create array example

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

IN the scipy lecture notes for [indexing](http://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/array_object.html#indexing-and-slicing)

There is an example problem, to create this array.

```
[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 4., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 5., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 6.]]
```

The problem for me is getting the extra blank row at the top. How do I acheive the example?

This is my current code.

```
d =np.zeros([5,],dtype=int) + np.diag(arange(2,7,1))

d
Out[66]: 
array([[2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 6]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `diag` and indexing alone using the `k` argument to `diag`:

```
np.diag(np.arange(2,7), k = -1)
```

gives:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0]])
```

That's almost right. You just need to lose the last column which you can do with an slice:

```
np.diag(np.arange(2,7), k = -1)[:, :-1]
```

which gives the desired result:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 6]])
```

Comment: Or make it too large on the other end: `np.diag(np.arange(1,7))[:,1:]`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html):

```
>>> zero_row = np.zeros((1,5))
>>> matrix   = np.diag(np.arange(2,7,1))
>>> np.append(zero_row, matrix, axis=0)
<<< array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 4., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 5., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 6.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of generating the array without `diag`.  Instead I index a diagonal set of elements in a `zeros` array:

```
In [167]: x = np.zeros((6,5))                                                     
In [168]: x[np.arange(1,6), np.arange(5)] = np.arange(2,7)                        
In [169]: x                                                                     
Out[169]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 4., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 5., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 6.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

m = np.zeros([5,])
n = np.diag(np.arange(2,7,1))

m = np.vstack((m,n))
print(m)
```

We can use `vstack`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `reshape` like so:

```
out = np.zeros((6, 5))                                                              
out.reshape(5, 6)[:, 5] = np.arange(2, 7)                                            
out                                                                                                         
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 4., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 5., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 6.]])
```

or very similarly:

```
out = np.zeros((6, 5))
out.reshape(-1)[5::6] = np.arange(2, 7)
out
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 4., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 5., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 6.]])
```

Both these methods are faster than everything posted so far:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def od_hpj():
    out = np.zeros((6, 5))
    out[np.arange(1,6), np.arange(5)] = np.arange(2,7)                        
    return out

def od_mm():
    return np.diag(np.arange(2,7), k = -1)[:, :-1]

def od_ks():
    m = np.zeros([5,])
    n = np.diag(np.arange(2,7,1))
    return np.vstack((m,n))

def od_as():
    zero_row = np.zeros((1,5))
    matrix   = np.diag(np.arange(2,7,1))
    return np.append(zero_row, matrix, axis=0)

def od_pp1():
    out = np.zeros((6, 5))
    out.reshape(5, 6)[:, 5] = np.arange(2, 7)
    return out

def od_pp2():
    out = np.zeros((6, 5))
    out.reshape(-1)[5::6] = np.arange(2, 7)
    return out

for n, o in list(globals().items()):
    if n.startswith("od_"):
        print(f"{n.replace('od_', ''):3s}: {timeit(o):.3f} us")
```

Sample run:

```
hpj: 3.379 us
mm : 2.952 us
ks : 7.804 us
as : 5.222 us
pp1: 1.735 us
pp2: 2.418 us
```